# stopPropagation in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, extjs5

I've been having trouble getting stopPropagation to work for my dataview.  Basically the issue is as follows;

- Select node in the dataview, this fires the select, selectionchange events
- Selected node has an image with an onClick event, this creates a report in a pop up window.
- When image is clicked I call stopPropagation to prevent the event being bubbled up to the dataview which would cause the deselect, selectionchange events to be fired.
- stopPropagation only seems to work in Firefox for me. Chrome and IE it seems to have no effect as the node is deselected and the unwanted events fired.

I've tried the following function on the onClick event

```
handleBubbleEvent: function(e) {
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Have also seen stopImmediatePropagation, preventDefault, stopEvent but these also has had no effect

I am doing all this inside an Ext XTemplate

```
<a href="#" title="Report" class="quicklinks journey_report" onClick="handleBubbleEvent(event); Ext.getCmp(...).generateReport(...); return false;"></a>
```

I'm wondering if this is an ExtJS 5 issue and the same code is working for an older version of ExtJS.  I just can't seem to stop the click event bubbling back up to the dataview which then fires the deselect and selectionchange events.

Could it be that it is a timing/order issue.  I use ExtJS's selectionchange event on the dataview whereas in the XTemplate I am using my own listener function?  I see stuff online referencing capturing/bubbling of events and as I'm not a web developer I'm struggling on this.

UPDATE:
I'm now looking at events and capturing/bubbling, it seems the capturing is going up to the parent and calling the deselect, selectionchange then going down into the actual click handler at which point I then call stopPropagation but it is too late at this stage.  Looking at creating my own listener for selectionchange with either target/delegate set so that it is only called when class != 'some class' and then a listener on 'some class' click to handle what I want and stopPropagation, if that makes any sense!

Comment: The event handler itself should probably also return false.

Comment: I should have added that the onClick code sits inside an Ext.XTemplate, so it looks something like this;  onClick=handleBubbleEvent(event); Ext.getCmp(...).generateReport(...); return false;

Answer (score 0):

Try using a setTimeout on any dom manipulation triggered by the event.target element's event handler so that the event bubbling completes before any of the dom manipulation occurs.

I had the same issue with Chrome, and (like with you) Firefox worked. I discovered that Chrome seems to get confused if you modify the dom before the event bubbling completes.

In my case, I was adding two elements to the document.body (a canvas and a fieldset) and by the time chrome bubbled the event, the event.target was incorrect (it thought "BODY" was the event.target.tagName -- WRONG!). I wrapped the DOM manipulation portion in a setTimeout like this:

```
    setTimeout(()=>
    {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        document.body.appendChild(fieldSet);            
    },0);
```

After this, chrome started reporting the correct element.target on the bubbled body click event. Maybe this same technique will help you get e.stopPropagation() to do its thing before the dom manipulation occurs.